# When selecting third item of dropdown the input box should appear

Tags: php

Hello I have a chained drop down the first one consists of three items, while selecting the first one the second drop down will display it's item at the same like this the second option.

The third one is Property ID I mean whenever I am selecting this one the input box which is disable should be visible otherwise it should be hidden.

Any one please ?

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Search Area</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function setOptions(chosen) {
var selbox = document.myform.status;

selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") 
{
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please Select one',' ');

}
if (chosen == "1") 
{
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please Select One');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('For Rent');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('For Sale');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('For Lease');
}
if (chosen == "2") 
{
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please Select One');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Approved');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Pending');
}
if (chosen == "3") 
{
   document.getElementById("propertyid").style.visibility= visibile;
}

}


</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="myform">

    <select name="dealtype" class="select" size="1" onchange= "setOptions(document.myform.dealtype.options[document.myform.dealtype.selectedIndex].value);">

<option value=" " selected="selected">Select Please One</option>
          <option value="1">Property Deal Type</option>
          <option value="2">Property Status </option>
          <option value="3">Property ID</option>
</select>


  <select name="status" size="1">
  <option value=" " selected="selected">Select Please One</option>        
  </select>
 <input type="text" onchange= "setOptions(document.myform.dealtype.options[document.myform.dealtype.selectedIndex].value);" name="search" id="propertyid" style="visibility:hidden"/>


</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of making `document.getElementById("propertyid")`-element visible if it's already visible?

Comment: no the input box is hidden when selecting the ProperyID from list so it should visibile

Comment: So set `id` to the input box and not to `option`

Comment: my code had a little problem so i fixed that.

Comment: AH ok I guess you already fixed it before I posted the answer, let me delete the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to simple your select box
 like this

```
<select name="dealtype" class="select" size="1" onchange= "setOptions(this.value);">

<option value=" " selected="selected">Select Please One</option>
          <option value="1">Property Deal Type</option>
          <option value="2">Property Status </option>
          <option value="3"Property ID</option>
</select>
```

and your js function should be as

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function setOptions(chosen) {
var selbox = document.myform.status;

selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") 
{
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please Select one',' ');

}
else if (chosen == "1") 
{
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please Select One');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('For Rent');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('For Sale');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('For Lease');
}
else if (chosen == "2") 
{
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please Select One');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Approved');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Pending');
}
else if (chosen == "3") 
{
   document.getElementById("propertyid").style.display = 'block';
}

}



</script>
```

and your hidden textbox should be as like this with id `propertyid`

`<input type="text" name="search" id="propertyid" style="display:none"/>`